# Set an element on a responsive image at fixed position using CSS

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I am trying to set an a tag element position on a responsive image fixed during responsive design.But the A tag element is not setting at fixed position.Here is what i tried.

```js
function SetSize() {
  var imgW = 1920;
  var imgH = 1080;
  var winW = $(window).width();
  var winH = $(window).height();
  var scaleW = winW / imgW;
  var scaleH = winH / imgH;
  var fixScale = Math.max(scaleW, scaleH);
  var setW = imgW * fixScale;
  var setH = imgH * fixScale;
  var moveX = Math.floor((winW - setW) / 2);
  var moveY = Math.floor((winH - setH) / 2);
  $('#bg').css({
    'width': setW,
    'height': setH,
    'left': moveX,
    'top': moveY
  });
}
```

```css
.status {
  left: 36.1%;
  top: 15.6%;
}

#contents a {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
</head>

<body>
  <img src="test.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" id="bg" />
  <div id="contents">
    <a href="" class="status">On</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean, are you wanting some sort of overlay ontop of the image which will stay in the same place when resized?

Comment: yes thats correct.Will show a status indication.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding `height: 100%` for the body (and `margin: 0`) to fix the height of `body`, which is the relative parent / position anchor for `img` and `a`. Also, I would apply `display: block` to the image to avoid descender space below it caused by being an inline element.

```js
function SetSize() {
  var imgW = 1920;
  var imgH = 1080;
  var winW = $(window).width();
  var winH = $(window).height();
  var scaleW = winW / imgW;
  var scaleH = winH / imgH;
  var fixScale = Math.max(scaleW, scaleH);
  var setW = imgW * fixScale;
  var setH = imgH * fixScale;
  var moveX = Math.floor((winW - setW) / 2);
  var moveY = Math.floor((winH - setH) / 2);
  $('#bg').css({
    'width': setW,
    'height': setH,
    'left': moveX,
    'top': moveY
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

img#bg {
  display: block;
}

.status {
  left: 36.1%;
  top: 15.6%;
}

#contents a {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
</head>

<body>
  <img src="test.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" id="bg" />
  <div id="contents">
    <a href="" class="status">On</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way that i have found to create an image overlay is to use `background-image` on a div with `position: relative` and then inside that div create the overlay div with `position: absolute`. All you have to do then is tell the `image-container` how big it needs to be and then the overlay will move to where it needs to move.

CSS

```
  .image-container{
      background-image: url('path/to/image.png');
      background-size: cover;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: relative;
  }

  .image-container .overlay{
     position: absolute;
     left: 36.1%;
     top: 15.6%;
  }
```

HTML

```
  <body>
     <div class="image-container">
        <div class="image-overlay">
           <a href="" class="status">On</a>
        </div>
     </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

for one thing your  tag isn't closed.